# Ramanujan's Nested Square Roots

Tags: number-theory

Well, while my friend was watching "The Man Who Knew Infinity"(Story of The Great Mathematician - THE Ramanujan), he came across the following equation ->

$3 = \sqrt{1+2{\sqrt{1+3\sqrt{1+4\sqrt{1+5.....\infty}}}}}$ (I hope you understand the series )

I actually found 1 method of proving this ->

We know that

$(x+1)^{2}=x^{2}+2x+1
          =1+x(x+2)$ -------------------> (1)

*Substituting $2$ in the above identity*

$(2+1)^{2}=1+2(2+2)$

$=>(3)^{2}=1+2(4)$

$=>3=\sqrt{1+2(4)} $ -------------------> (2)

*Similarly , substituting $3$ in the above identity*

$(3+1)^{2}=1+3(3+2)$

$=>(4)^{2}=1+3(5)$

$=>4=\sqrt{1+3(5)}$ -------------------> (3)

*Similarly , substituting $4$ in the above identity*

$(4+1)^{2}=1+4(4+2)$

$=>(5)^{2}=1+4(6)$

$=>5=\sqrt{1+4(6)}$ -------------------> (4)

**Substituting value of (3) & (4) in (2)**

$(2+1)^{2}=1+2(2+2)$

$=>(3)^{2}=1+2(4)$

$=>3=\sqrt{1+2(4)}$

$=>3=\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{1+3(5)}}$

$=>3=\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{1+3\sqrt{1+4(6)}}}$

We notice we can do this **FOREVER**, thus , arriving at

$3 = \sqrt{1+2{\sqrt{1+3\sqrt{1+4\sqrt{1+5.....\infty}}}}}$

Is there any other method to arrive at the given solution , in fact , **PROVE** the given equation ??

Comment: I also have 1 question !! What if Ramanujan was On MSE ?? ;-)

Comment: they are already registred : Ramanujan viki, Ramanujan-Dirac and Ramanujan himself :)

Answer (score 0):

You can find it [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_radical). You basically find a generalization of the function, make it a recursive formula, and then solve it.